# Windows Network and Installing Applications to SourceServer directory

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, deployment

I have been asked to help with a school's network, specifically installing applications across workstations, but I am not sure how their current scheme works.

On the main server, there is an 'Apps' directory which contains a 'SourceServer' directory in which many applications are installed, and a 'SourceClient' directory (empty). Network machines all have this Apps directory mapped as a network drive, and all apps are available in the Start menu (stored in a sibling directory of Apps).

Are these details typical of a particular system?
Is adding a new application as simple as installing it on the server to the SourceServer directory and dropping a shortcut in the Start menu directory?

Thank you.

Comment: I am not familiar with either of the source directories you mention.  Do you happen to know what (if any) management tools your schools use?  Some googling leads to references of [Source Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680641(v=vs.85).aspx) but I'm not confident that's what you're dealing with.  If you're starting with zero background info, you may need to audit a machine to understand how all of the parts are configured. Feel free to edit your question to include any additional details.